# Lol disabled rewards

Tags: league-of-legends

I've been playing league of legends and I'm a level 16, but the thing that gets my concerned about this game is when you finish a match, like whenever you look set the reward you get from it there is always disabled Xp and ip. I would like to know why this is and how to prevent it

Comment: that is the xp and ip boost that you need to buy. it's shown to give you an idea what xp and ip boost would give you if you had it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the xp and ip is the bonus ip you would get if you had boosts. You can buy boosts for xp and ip to faster get forward but they cost game money(RP), which you get by putting in real money. So it's not something you are missing out of as much as it's something you might get as a bonus. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Riot also very seldom has Double IP weekends/events. The most recent being this past week (April 25th-27th).